# Determining camera parameters

Tags: image-processing, projection, photography, photogrammetry

Given a picture taken by a simple digital that contains an image of a rectangle of known dimensions. How can I - to some degree of accuracy - determine the parameters of this camera?

I am mostly interested in Pan-, Tilt- and Swing angles.
Optionally distance to the rectangle would be nice.

I acknowledge the fact that the focal length and resolution of the camera should be known, but  it can be assumed that they are available (for example through exif metadata).

Are there any simple algorithms for this problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are camera calibration algorithms.  A commonly used one is [Zhang's algorithm](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/papers/tr98-71.pdf).

For more information regarding calibrating cameras, a good source is [Hartley and Zisserman's textbook](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook1.html)

Comment: +1: Zhang's method works well, and Multiple View Geometry is a must read!

Comment: I have seen Zhang's paper before and have discarded it as being to complicated on the math side :). So if you know of a source that can explain better I would like to hear about it. 

I have ordered Hartley and Zisserman, it should be in on friday thanks for that tip!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall Multiple View Geometry being much easier with regards to math than what the Zhang paper is.
Computer vision in general really puts your math skills on test.

Comment: True enough! 

However, by reading I came to the conclusion that, for my problem, it might be enough to only know the transformation matrix that  caused my original rectangle (which I can measure in pixels) to the trapezoid in the image. (which can also be measured in pixels. This should reduce the number of parameters. 

Perhaps I should rephrase the question or ask a new one

Comment: I think opencv implements Zhang algorithm

Comment: If you have access to MATLAB try http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/ . Remember when you calibrate your camera it works for only one focus of the camera (therefore auto-focusing must be disable)

Answer (score 1):

for a slightly simpler introduction and sample code see (chap 12 IIRC)

[image: https://covers.oreilly.com/images/9780596516130/cat.gif]